# How to convert uint8List to image in flutter web

Tags: android, flutter, web, flutter-web

I want to take a screenshot of any widget and then share it to WhatsApp or any other app. But from the screenshot widget, I get uint8List type of image but I want to convert it into image type and then Share it with Flutter_Share plugin, so I have to convert it into Image. How to do that?

```
controller
                        .capture(delay: Duration(milliseconds: 10))
                        .then((capturedImage) async {
                      final imagePath = await File('/image.png').create();
                      await imagePath.writeAsBytes(capturedImage!);
                      await Share.shareFiles([imagePath.path]);
                    }).catchError((onError) {
                      print(onError);
                    });
```

Here I am trying to convert it to imagePath but I got "FormatException: Unexpected extension byte (at offset 0)" this type of error, Also I have tried,

```
File img = File.fromRawPath(imageFile!);
```

but still, I got an error.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Image.memory

```
Image.memory(listHere);
```

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Image/Image.memory.html